# Oracle Stored Procedure to use another Schema's views

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, schema

I'm writing a Stored Procedure to automate a task, and in one of the steps I need to Select data from a view that's in another user's schema.

I can query the data from that View outside the Stored Procedure but apparently not in a SP under my schema.

Is this by design or am I missing something? Are there any workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: post the code buddy!

Comment: From [help/on-topic]: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."

Answer (score 1):

More a comment than an answer, trying to clarify the issue. I believe the answer could be in the following code or in the comment by Boneist.

If you give the needed privileges on the view, I see no reason why a SP should not work in querying a view from another schema.

For example, if I create a view in schema HR and give `SELECT` privilege to my user

```
SQL> conn hr/###@xe
Connected.
SQL> create or replace view testView as select 1 as one from dual;

View created.

SQL> grant select on testView to alek;

Grant succeeded.
```

and then I build a procedure in my schema

```
SQL> conn alek/###@xe
Connected.
SQL> create or replace procedure testSelectView is
  2  begin
  3    for i in ( select * from hr.testView) loop
  4      dbms_output.put_line(i.one);
  5    end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.
```

from within my schema, both a query and the procedure work:

```
SQL> select * from hr.testView;

       ONE
----------
         1

SQL> exec testSelectView;
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Most likely in the OP's situation, the grant on the table has been given to a role and the role granted to the OP's schema. It would work if the grant was given directly to the table, which you've demonstrated in your answer.

Comment: @Boneist: Given the undetailed question, my doubt was if the OP had a privilege issue, (in this case I believe the issue is exactly what you say) or maybe something not related to privileges, for example a missing INTO or something like that.

Comment: Ah yeah; now you say that I can see the ambiguity of the OP's question. Ho hum!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a privilege issue. Inside a PL/SQL block you have only privileges which are granted **directly** to you, privileges granted through a role (for example `DBA` role) do not apply.

Run `grant select on ... to ...;` or `grant select any table to ...;`, then it should work.